# Authenticating with gmail using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email with a form using PhpMailer but it does not work well.
With a localhost xampp it works prefectly but when uploaded to my website it causing errors,
after checking it I understood that is is because gmail blocking me (I already enabled less secure apps on gmail)
The only way it seems to work is by removing the isSmtp() from the code but I don't think that it is very good idea.
Please any suggestions?
Code below:

```
    if (array_key_exists('attachment', $_FILES)) {
    $img_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    $upload = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment']['name']));
    $uploadfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$img_name;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        if (!$err) {
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
          //  $mail->isSMTP();
            // $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            // set a port
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            // set login detail for gmail account
            $mail->Username = '******';
            $mail->Password = '********';
            $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
            // set subject
            $mail->setFrom($email, $username);
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->addReplyTo($email, $username);
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded image');
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Contact form: Testing Feedback';
            $mail->Body = $reason;
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                $msg .= "Message sent!";
            }
        }
    } else {
                $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
```

Getting the following errors

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in /storage/ssd1/218/15386218/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:2063 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd1/218/15386218/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1878): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #1 /storage/ssd1/218/15386218/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1601): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Thu, 12 N...', 'This is a multi...') #2 /storage/ssd1/218/15386218/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1437): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #3 /storage/ssd1/218/15386218/public_html/index.php(72): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #4 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd1/218/15386218/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2063
```

Comment: Those look like they may be your real credentials. Please always censor usernames and passwords when sharing code.

Comment: Please also share any errors you're getting. We don't know what happens when you say it "doesn't work well" or "there is a problem".

Comment: @RoAchterberg Thank you my bad!! added Errors in the issue

Comment: Commenting out `isSMTP` will only move the problem, not solve it. Please read what the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide says [about authentication with gmail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps). It's mainly that gmail does many non-standard things that make it difficult to connect; it's gmail breaking things, not the client.

Comment: There are several reasons that it might work locally and not on your server: your hosting provider may be redirecting traffic; gmail is detecting a login location that's different from your usual one and imposing additional limits. If you set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`, you will at least be able to see what the server is saying, and what it says is *very* likely to be covered in the troubleshooting guide.